# Accessing self when using python plotly/dash during app.callback

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, self

I am creating a live updating graph using plotly/dash and python. Passing the variable `self` in python is unfortunately throwing errors. I have made a minmimal example below to outline the problem.

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly
import random
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from collections import deque
import time
import numpy as np


class PlotlyDashboard:
    _X = deque(maxlen = 20)
    _X.append(1)
    
    _Y = deque(maxlen = 20)
    _Y.append(1)
    
    _app = dash.Dash(__name__)

    def __init__(self):
        self._app.layout = html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Graph(id = 'live-graph', animate = True),
            dcc.Interval(
                id = 'graph-update',
                interval = 1000,
                n_intervals = 0
            ),
        ]
        )

    @_app.callback(
        Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
        [Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals') ]
    )
    def update_graph_scatter(self, n):
        data = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
                x=list(self._X),
                y=list(self._Y),
                name='Scatter',
                mode= 'lines+markers'
        )
    
        return {'data': [data],
                'layout' : go.Layout(xaxis=dict(range=[min(self._X),max(self._X)]),yaxis = dict(range = [min(self._Y),max(self._Y)]),)}

    def update(self, y):
        self._X.append(self._X[-1] + 1)
        self._Y.append(y)
    
    def start(self):
        self._app.run_server(port=8050)

live_plotter = PlotlyDashboard()

live_plotter.start()
while True:
    live_plotter.update(np.random.normal(0,1))
    time.sleep(1)
```

The graph updates once a second with new data that is provided via the `update` function. The `update` function updates the data queues stored in `self`. During the `@app.callback` which also happens every second it consults `self` to get the current state of the data before plotting, but I get the below error when doing so

```
output_value = func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
TypeError: update_graph_scatter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'
```

The error goes away if I remove `self` as an arg in the `update_graph_scatter` method, but then the internals of the method cannot access self which causes a different error. Any help that can be provided on how I can access self or an equivalent common store that both the update method and @app.callback tagged method can consult will be much appreciated.

Edit: By using rob's solution and a bit of threading I was able to solve the issue. Please see my solution below on how to instantiate the class in one thread (must be done because app_server is blocking)
and then update the data the class is plotting using the main thread.

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly
import random
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from collections import deque
import time
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread
class PlotlyDashboard:
    _X = deque(maxlen = 20)
    _X.append(1)
    
    _Y = deque(maxlen = 20)
    _Y.append(1)
    
    _app = dash.Dash(__name__)

    def __init__(self):
        self._app.layout = html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Graph(id = 'live-graph', animate = True),
            dcc.Interval(
                id = 'graph-update',
                interval = 1000,
                n_intervals = 0
            ),
        ]
        )
        if self._app is not None and hasattr(self, "callbacks"):
            self.callbacks(self._app)

    def callbacks(self, _app):
        @_app.callback(
            Output("live-graph", "figure"), [Input("graph-update", "n_intervals")]
        )
        def update_graph_scatter(n):
            # let's update data here to show class callbacks are working
            data = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
                x=list(self._X), y=list(self._Y), name="Scatter", mode="lines+markers"
            )

            return {
                "data": [data],
                "layout": go.Layout(
                    xaxis=dict(range=[min(self._X), max(self._X)]),
                    yaxis=dict(range=[min(self._Y), max(self._Y)]),
                ),
            }
    def update(self, y):
        self._X.append(self._X[-1] + 1)
        self._Y.append(y)
    
    def start(self):
        self._app.run_server(port=8050)

live_plotter = PlotlyDashboard()

def starter():
    live_plotter.start()

plot_thread = Thread(target=starter)
plot_thread.start()
while True:
        live_plotter.update(np.random.normal(0,1))
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I have answered the scope of your question.  How to have **callbacks** as class methods
- fundamentally scope them as static methods within a class method.
- you have assumed that `run_server()` is non blocking, i.e. returns control immediately after server has been started back to controlling process.  It is not - hence I have put call to `self.update()` into callback

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly
import random
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from collections import deque
import time

class PlotlyDashboard:
    _X = deque(maxlen=20)
    _X.append(1)

    _Y = deque(maxlen=20)
    _Y.append(1)

    _app = dash.Dash(__name__)

    def __init__(self):
        self._app.layout = html.Div(
            [
                dcc.Graph(id="live-graph", animate=True),
                dcc.Interval(id="graph-update", interval=1000, n_intervals=0),
            ]
        )

        if self._app is not None and hasattr(self, "callbacks"):
            self.callbacks(self._app)

    def callbacks(self, _app):
        @_app.callback(
            Output("live-graph", "figure"), [Input("graph-update", "n_intervals")]
        )
        def update_graph_scatter(n):
            # let's update data here to show class callbacks are working
            self.update()
            data = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
                x=list(self._X), y=list(self._Y), name="Scatter", mode="lines+markers"
            )

            return {
                "data": [data],
                "layout": go.Layout(
                    xaxis=dict(range=[min(self._X), max(self._X)]),
                    yaxis=dict(range=[min(self._Y), max(self._Y)]),
                ),
            }

    def update(self):
        self._X.append(self._X[-1] + 1)
        self._Y.append(self._Y[-1] + self._Y[-1] * random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1))

    def start(self):
        print("starting")
        self._app.run_server(port=8050)
        # this will never be seen !!!!
        print("started")


live_plotter = PlotlyDashboard()


live_plotter.start()
# this code will never run as run_server() is a blocking not a sub-process
while True:
    live_plotter.update()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply Rob. I realised it was blocking when I moved the _X and _Y outside the class so that I could update without self. I also realised my example was slightly wrong in that the update function should take extra arguments aside from self and I ammended the original example to describe this. I was in the middle of updating my reply when you commented apologies for this.


The intention was the class is instantiated externally and the server is started. Then separate calls to the update function change what data is plotted like in the amended example.

Comment: Thanks Rob, i was able to use your solution to fix it nonetheless by working around the fact that app_server is blocking by using another thread to run the server and using the main thread to update the data. Much appreciated. The solution is in my edit.